# Git's <refname>@{<date>} format doesn't always work?

Tags: git

Looking at the [gitrevisions docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), it seems like I can do something like:

```
git show "master@{3 minutes ago}":foo
git show "master@{1 minute ago}":foo
git log "master@{20 minutes ago}"
git log "master@{1 minute ago}"
```

where the `foo` above is just a simple text file.

So those seem to work, showing different content for `foo` or for the log.  But if I

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
cd git
```

and now if I do

```
git log "master@{100 days ago}"
```

then I get the same log as if I am doing `git log` -- how can this be made to work?

Answer (score 1):

The `@{foo}` syntax accesses reflogs, not the branch history. A reflog stores changes you made to a branch locally. It makes a note when you commit something, but also when you reset/rewrite the branch in some way. So, reflogs can be used to undo rather invasive changes made to a branch.

The flip side of that is that the syntax can only be used to refer to changes you made *yourself*, in exactly that copy of the repository – but you can access changes that aren't visible in the history, specifically changes that *rewrite* history.

If you want to filter normal log output by date, look at the options `--since`/`after` and `--until`/`before`.

Comment: yup, so I tried `git show "master@{1 year ago}":ws.c` and it gave me the current version... I had to do `git show d932:ws.c` to get the previous version

Comment: if I redirect the file using `git show "master@{1 year ago}":ws.c > ws.c.1.year.ago.c`, then it shows `warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Mon, 12 May 2014 02:46:08 -0700.` but if I don't redirect to a file, then there is no warning.  I think this can be a bug... for somebody reading the file and think the file 1 year ago was as shown on screen

Comment: if I say `git show d932:ws.c` and I can get the version as of a year ago (by inspecting the git log), and then `git show "master@{1 year ago}":ws.c` can't, then I think git isn't so perfected yet

Comment: The syntax is for accessing reflogs, not for accessing history. You don't have anything in your reflog reaching that far back, hence you get no result that far back (AFAIK the `@{}` finds the closest possible match, in your case probably the oldest entry in the reflog). Feel free to propose/implement an additional syntax for accessing history relative to a committish.

Comment: Regarding the warning you described: chances are git *does* output the warning but your pager immediately overwrites the screen content and so you can't see it. This is not so much a bug in Git as a general issue happening with redirecting STDOUT to a pager but not STDERR. I'm not aware of a way to prevent this with popular pagers. Workaround example: `git show blah@{yesterday} 2>&1 | less`

Comment: I think if it is due to the pager, then it might make sense to first output the warning, let the user press Enter first, and then show the content of the file